# No Test File but NextJs still display this `When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):`

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am wondering where this error message is coming from. I scanned for all test-related files. **.test.tsx, **.test.js and *.spec.tsx etc. Any idea why this is showing up even when there are no tests in a project.

Note:

- Before you mark duplicate, notice, there are no test files whatsoever in my project.
- I have scan inline test cases against keywords `it, describe, test)` but no luck

```
When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):

act(() => {
  /* fire events that update state */
});
/* assert on the output */

This ensures that you're testing the behavior the user would see in the browser.
```

Comment: What command are you running to get this output?

Comment: dev server with NextJS  `yarn dev`